# My proof for "$\Gamma =\{X\in \mathbf{R}^{n\times n} \mid X \succeq 0, \text{Tr}(X)=1\}$ is compact"

Tags: general-topology, matrices, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

This problem comes from:

[How to prove the compactness of the set of Hermitian positive semidefinite matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581990/how-to-prove-the-compactness-of-the-set-of-hermitian-positive-semidefinite-matri)

In short, we want to prove

> $$\Gamma =\{X\in \mathbf{R}^{n\times n} \mid X \succeq 0, \text{Tr}(X)=1\}$$ 
>   is compact.

Can I prove this in a terse way:

> $\Gamma$ is the intersection of PSD cone, which is convex and closed, and the hyperplane $\{X \mid \text{Tr}(X)=1\}$, so $\Gamma$ is compact.

So it looks like the following graph:
[image: Intersection]

If not, which part I should say more?

Comment: The conclusion "so $\Gamma$ is compact" seems like a non sequitur, why does that follow?

Comment: Take the first quadrant of $xy$-plane and the hyperplane $y=x$. Is the intersection compact?

Comment: @A.G. I think yes since there is a boundary $x=0$($y-axis$) and $y=0$$(x-axis)$ so it is closed and of course it is bounded (the length of intersection is bounded).  Am I correct?

Comment: @littleO I provide a picture in my proof, that is what I think why that follows. Could you please let me know why that may not follow? For example, boundary of closed convex cone does not guarantee closedness.

Comment: @Denny Not really. Points $(t,t)$ where $t\to+\infty$ belong to the intersection. It is unbounded. This example shows that it is important how the hyperplane is located with respect to the cone.

Comment: @A.G. I see. I think $Tr(X)=1$ shows how the hyperplane is located w.r.t the cone as depicted in the figure.

Comment: I believe the picture doesn't help because the positive semidefinite cone doesn't look like that.  It's difficult to visualize the positive semidefinite cone because it's a subset of $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$.  Even if we identify $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ and take $n = 2$, we still must visualize a subset of $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: A $2 \times 2$ symmetric matrix can be identified with a point in $\mathbb R^3$, which yields this visualization of the positive semidefinite cone: http://img.blog.csdn.net/20140131000456046?watermark/2/text/aHR0cDovL2Jsb2cuY3Nkbi5uZXQvZnJvZ19pbl9hX3dlbGw=/font/5a6L5L2T/fontsize/400/fill/I0JBQkFCMA==/dissolve/70/gravity/SouthEast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some kind of further argument to prove boundedness, in my opinion. I propose this one.

Since the matrices are (symmetric) positive-semidefinite, their eigenvalues are positive. Since the trace is $1$, all the eigenvalues are in $[0,1]$. Therefore, if we consider the operator norm on $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ $$\lVert A\rVert_2=\sup_{v\ne 0}\frac{\lVert Av\rVert}{\lVert v\rVert}$$
your set is bounded with respect to it since $\lVert A\rVert_2\le\max\limits_{\lambda\in\operatorname{Spec A}}\lvert \lambda\rvert$.

**Addition:** Fact is that you somehow need to prove that your subspace does not cut the cone in a bad way (recall that not only ellypses are [conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section), but parabolas and hyperbolas too!)

Comment: The concept behind your answer is to construct a ball which contains the set. But where is the origin? I mean $\|A-O\|_2\leq \text{max} |\lambda|$, where is $O$? This $O$ should be in $\Gamma$.

Comment: The origin is the zero matrix, which is not in $\Gamma$ because it needs not be. A set is bounded if and only if it is contained in a ball, regardless of where the center is.